# Get Only Video and not cortos videos

Tags: youtube-api

Good morning

I am using the youtube api to get the latest videos from a channel, but I also get the short videos that are like instagram or tiktok reels, is there any way to not get these videos?

I leave the endoint I am using

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?channelId=${channel_id}&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=${totalVideos}&key=${API_KEY_YOUTUBE}
```

Greetings and thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you check the [Search.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) method you will notice that it does not have any way of limiting the data that is returned.

You will need to remove these locally.

It may be worth adding a feature request to the issue [forumn](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:186600%2B)